# Google apps script. Date-time values is being changed to 'one hour later'. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have date-time values in my google sheets. Copying them to another sheet. While this, using range.getValues() writing the values to the array then writing the array to another sheet. During this process, date-time value is being changed to 'one hour later'. why.
for example, this is the value in source 20/01/2020 15:44:00 and the value at the destination is 20/01/2020 16:44:00.

sample code.

```
       ...
   var range = pmSheet.getRange(6, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
   var pmRangeValues = range.getValues();
   ...
   NT = [];
   for (var i in pmRangeValues)
      {
       var ddd = pmRangeValues[i][10].toString().trim();
       if (ddd == 'CHECK VALUE') 
       {
        NT.push([pmRangeValues[i][0], pmRangeValues[i][1], pmRangeValues[i][2], pmRangeValues[i][3],
                 pmRangeValues[i][4], pmRangeValues[i][5], pmRangeValues[i][6], pmRangeValues[i][7], 
                 pmRangeValues[i][8], pmRangeValues[i][9], pmRangeValues[i][10], pmRangeValues[i][11], 
                 pmRangeValues[i][12], pmRangeValues[i][13], pmRangeValues[i][14], pmRangeValues[i][15], 
                 pmRangeValues[i][16], pmRangeValues[i][20], pmRangeValues[i][21]]);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the timezone settings for the script and the spreadsheets to see if the match.

Comment: thanks for comment, how to check those?

Comment: In the spreadsheet it's in File/Spreadsheet Settings and in the script editor it's in File/Project Properties

Comment: the issue is solved. they were different. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cooper's comment. The timezone settings of the SpreadsheetApp and the Project were different.

Comment: please mark this as the answer by checking the tick.